# Office 365 manifest size limit

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

While trying use the office365 admin portal to upload an add-in for our organization we encountered the following problem:
On the final step of the dialog, an error message appears claiming the following:

[image: screenshot]

With devtools open I can see that the failing request contains the following error message: "FailedWriteToExchange". This is strange, since uploading the [Contoso Citations add-in maninfest](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/blob/master/Word/manifest/CitationSample.xml) works just fine.

The manifests will work properly if it is sideloaded in Word Desktop (office365), and all XSD checks pass.

With a little bit of trial and error it seems that there is a limit to how large the manifest-files can be. I tested [different versions](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/826641b7f5e9c6221f0572612fbeb545) of the Contoso manifest by padding them with gibberish resource strings until the upload failed. When the manifest size exceeded about 36400 bytes, the upload failed. Does anyone know about this size limit? Is there a way to work around it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide link to your manifest? It is hard to determine why this is failing from the error message alone.

Comment: I uploaded two versions of the manifest [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/826641b7f5e9c6221f0572612fbeb545), one. One i can, and one I cannot upload. The difference is the ID of the add-in, and the padding in Xml comments.

Comment: Minor update for this issue: I have had contact with the Microsoft Teams, and the engineering team is investigating this issue. They can reproduce.